# How can I know in advance where cabal will place a generated executable?

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I run `cabal build` for my project, it places my compiled executable in

```sh
dist-newstyle/build/$PLATFORM/$GHC/$PACKAGE-$VERSION/x/$PACKAGE/build/$PACKAGE/$PACKAGE
```

I'm using a `Makefile` to run `cabal build` as needed when I need to run the executable.

Since I'm working on different platforms at various times, I need a way to tell my `Makefile` what to expect the `$PLATFORM` value to be.

There's a couple ways I could go about this:

- run `cabal build` once unconditionally, and then use wildcards:

  ```
  BIN := $(wildcard dist-newstyle/build/*/ghc-*/foo-*/x/foo/build/foo/foo)
  ```
- use `uname` to predict what the platform will be

  ```
  BIN := dist-newstyle/build/$(shell uname -m)-$(shell uname -s | some magic)/ghc-$(shell ghc --version | some magic)/foo-$(VERSION)/x/foo/build/foo/foo
  ```
- give up on making sure the binary is up to date within the `Makefile` and just run `cabal run` unconditionally

Any of those *would* work, but I would like to know if I could just ask `cabal` to tell me where it expects to place an executable.

Is there a `cabal` command I can run to tell me what `$PLATFORM` and/or `$GHC` values it detects?

Comment: This would be _really_ useful! (Or alternatively a cabal command that allows to say “build the executable and then place it in this specific location”.)

Comment: What else does the Makefile build?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid [Some rust code](https://github.com/rampion/advent-of-code/blob/master/2020/day/06/Makefile).

Comment: @rampion Ah, OK. Well, fundamentally Make is a build system, and Cabal is a build system... Trying to switch two different build systems together seems like asking for trouble. But good luck! (My personal feeling would be to just `cabal run` and leave it at that; if Cabal changes its file layout someday, it won't break.)

Comment: Isn't copying executables the purpose of `cabal install`?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I guess I could use `cabal install` with a custom `--installdir`, but wouldn't that still install the dependencies in `~/.cabal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since cabal 3.8, you can use the [`list-bin`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.8/cabal-commands.html#cabal-list-bin) command:

```
$ cabal list-bin my-executable-name
```

That will print the path at which cabal will place the executable if built. Note that it doesn't actually guarantee that the executable is built, so depending on your use case you might want to check that too.

Answer (score 3):

Say you just ran `cabal build` and produced a `foo` binary somewhere in the `dist-newstyle/` directory. You can now run:

```bash
cabal exec which foo
```

This will print out the absolute path to the `foo` executable.

**Note:** It may be necessary to run `cabal exec --verbose=0 which foo` so that `cabal` does not print out extra information about packages or configuration.

#### Why does this work?

`cabal exec` lets you run commands with the same environment used when running other cabal commands, like `cabal build`. So you can run `printenv` and `cabal exec printenv` to see how it adds and changes some environment variables. Notice that it adds the whole `dist-newstyle/` path to your `PATH` variable!

So saying `cabal exec which foo` works because it is just like running `which foo`, but with the extended `PATH` variable.

This means you can extract the `dist-newstyle/` path itself using a fancier command:

```bash
cabal exec --verbose=0 printenv PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep dist-newstyle | head -1
```

This may be useful if you need to know the path before you run `cabal build`, in which case the binary will not exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

`cabal exec which $EXENAME$` will give you the full path of the compiled executable.